# Jasmin array of Strings declaration/initialization error

Tags: jvm, jasmin

I'm writing a compiler that generates Jasmin code and want to create an array declaration as follows:

```
string[] name = { "asd", "asd" };
```

This currently generates the following code:

```
ldc 2               ; array size
newarray char       ; create new array of chars
astore 8            ; store array at loc 8
ldc "asd"           ; push value 1 onto stack
ldc 0               ; push index onto stack
aload 8             ; push array reference onto stack
aastore             ; store value in array at index
ldc "asd"           ; push value 2 onto stack
ldc 1               ; push index onto stack
aload 8             ; push array reference onto stack
aastore             ; store value in array at index
```

I thought this was the correct way, but I'm getting the following error:

```
java.lang.VerifyError: (class: helloworld, method: main signature: ([Ljava/lang/String;)V) Expecting to find array of objects or arrays on stack
```

Am I pushing things onto the stack in the wrong order? Or should I use a different type than char at the newarray line. If so, What's the correct type to use for Strings?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Never mind, I solved it already.

Should have used the following line to create an array of objects of type String:

```
anewarray Ljava/lang/String;
```